# Check if all children objects belong to same parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.1, Ruby 1.8.7

I have `Group`, which `:has_many => :items`

I have `Item`, which `:belongs_to => :group`

Then, I sometimes run a search which returns many items - which may or may not all belong to the same group.

Is there a way to check in the view if all items in the returned array belong to the same parent (group)?

The best I can think of is this:

```
##Application Helper
def belongs_to_same_group(items)
  group = items.first.group
  items.each do |item|
    return false if item.group != group
  end
  return true
end
```

But I'm guessing ruby or rails has some great one-liner for these situations that I don't know about/am not skillful enough to think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a one liner:

```
items.map(&:group_id).uniq.length == 1
```

or, another way to write what you already did:

```
items.all? {|item| item.group_id == items.first.group_id }
```

Comment: map(&:group_id) would be better - you avoid fetching the group object

Comment: Arg. I just saw .all? earlier today. This cold is killing me! Going with the map. Thanks!